# Datetime picker is not working in Grocery CRUD with Twitter Bootsrap Theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grocery-crud

I'm using grocery CRUD and Twitter Bootstrap. I'm using datetime format for post date. I am able to pick the date but unable to pick the time values. I checked out jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js still didn't get any solutions. Attaching a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtDLY.png) with this post.

Please let me know if you guys know any solutions for that!

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the bootstrap and jquery libraries call from bootstrap theme (maybe another version is already loaded from template or page)
To do so simply add these lines in your grocery_crud setup:

```
$crud->unset_bootstrap();
$crud->unset_jquery();
```

Also, have you checked that the related datatable field are in DATETIME or TIMESTAMP format?
If not you can change the type definition using:

```
$crud->change_field_type('name_of_field_where_datetime_is_recorded','date');
```

or:

```
$crud->change_field_type('name_of_field_where_datetime_is_recorded','timestamp');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically instruct the datepicker to allow for date & time.